What is $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\frac{1}{k}}}{n}$
What I was trying to do, was to prove if $\lim _{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ then $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n} = L$ is true or not. After some trials and errors, I found the series $a_k=k^{\frac{1}{k}}$ where $$\lim _{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$ and according to wolframalpha, $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\frac{1}{k}}}{n}=0$$but I doubt this, as $x^{\frac{1}{x}}>1$ for $x>1$ thus $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\frac{1}{k}}}{n}\geq1$
I would appreciate proof of the proposition, or counterexample, or an extra reasons on why $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\frac{1}{k}}}{n}=0$

The general assertion follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem WolframAlpha is incorrect.

What data from Wolfram Alpha makes you believe it?

Try typing "integrate sin(pi x)/(x*(1-x)) from 0 to 1" into WA.  Sometimes it says $0$, which is absurd since the integrand is positive on $(0,1)$. Also sometimes it says $3.70387$, which is accurate.  Whichever answer you get, try asking WA again and you'll get the other answer eventually (it always happens to me).

Don't say you doubt the answer can be zero in your example, but rather that you know the answer is not zero in your example, as you showed us a simple reason the limit can't be zero in that example: the $n$th term is always at least $1$.
To prove your goal, a nice way to streamline things is to reduce to the case $L = 0$. When $a_n \to L$, set $b_n= a_n - L$, so $b_n \to 0$.  Then
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{n} - L = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-L)}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}{n}, 
$$
so proving $(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)/n \to L$ is equivalent to proving $(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k)/n \to 0$.  Thus the general result you want to show is equivalent to the special case $L = 0$, so you may assume $L = 0$.
